# when page loads. focus should be on first control

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have a login page. Whenever the page loads, the cursor should blink in the first textbox only that is for entering a userid.

I've written javascript like this, but I am using Master Pages now.

this is my script:

```
function fcus(x)
{
  x.focus();
}

<asp:TextBox id="textbox1" onload="javascript:fcus(this);">
```

and where I have to call this method, I write on onload event of textbox but it gives an error.

Can you tell me where I have to call this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use form's DefaultFocus property (ASP.NET 2.0 and above)?

```
<form defaultfocus=“textbox1”>
```

You might need to do this programmatically, depending on your scenario.

Look into:

```
Page.Form.DefaultFocus
```

To [do it programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlform.defaultfocus.aspx).

Comment: ok its working fine. if i have master page and in child page i have the login page then how can i call the method thanku mr.richardod

Comment: haa! i got it thank u very much mr.RichardOD it is working fine

Answer (score 1):

Or a bit of jQuery, just dropped into your page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(<yourtextboxselector>).focus();

});
```

http://jquery.com/

Comment: it is working i write like this in page load

Page.Form.DefaultFocus = txtoldPassword.ClientID ;

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function like below at the end of the textbox.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt23" runat="server" Text="<%$ appSettings:applicationTitle %>" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text="<%$ appSettings:applicationTitle %>" />
<asp:Label ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text="<%$ appSettings:applicationTitle %>" />
     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     fcus(document.getElementById('TextBox1'));
    </script>  

 <br />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hidField" runat="server" />


    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Create" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: ok himadri once again this is suryasasidhar. ya i got it i write the code in page load  like this
Page.Form.DefaultFocus = txtoldPassword.ClientID ;